# Mark documents and show them in another Web Part

Tags: javascript, document-library, library, tagging

I wanted to know, if there is any way for users, to mark documents in a library and show those marked documents in a certain Web Part (customized to every user himself). I know there is a method in SharePoint like tagging documents, but unfortunately the MySites-functions are deactivated due to the concern governance. So might there be any script for fulfilling this requirement?

We use SharePoint 2013 (we don't have SharePoint Designer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if we don't have tagging and we don't have Designer for custom scripts, then we are left with some workaround. We can have a column as Mark with radio button Yes or No. User can select Yes to mark the particular document. Once marked, we can have a view to filter data based on MARK column and can show data with MARK as yes on a webpart.

Other than this option will be to have some custom solution on the library.